# Align legend text along a certain character within tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

Suppose we have the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%legend cell align={&+},?
             legend entries={a+b, aaaa+bbb},]
    \addplot {x};
    \addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Is it possible to align text in a legend with respect to a certain character?** e.g. like we might do in an align environment

```
\begin{align}
    a &+ b\\
    aaaa &+ bbb
\end{align}
```

I know we can do `legend cell align=left` etc. but this will only work for the above case when the legend entries themselves meet a certain criteria.

As an aside, where do I find a comprehensive documentation page for `pgfplots`? I have been referring to [this](http://bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf) although it is not all inclusive.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! To answer the second part of the question, you can find the documentation of ``pgfplots`` on CTAN, on [this page](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots).

Comment: You do realize that all externalize does is run TikZ using standalone in a separate process and use \includegraphics for the image file created.

Comment: Right... In the end I just need something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71488/pgfplot-plotting-a-large-dataset) and your solution works with externalize anyway, despite your chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to do it.  See also `\mathrlap` and `\mathllap` from mathtools.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize% sorry, not on my system
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%legend cell align={&+},?
             legend entries={\phantom{aaaa}\llap{a}+\rlap{b}\phantom{bbb}, aaaa+bbb},]
    \addplot {x};
    \addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to achieve this alignment.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
% \usepgfplotslibrary{external}
% \tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%legend cell align={&+},?
             legend entries={\eqmakebox[r1][r]{$b$}\eqmakebox[l1][l]{${}+b$},
              \eqmakebox[r1][r]{$aaaa$}\eqmakebox[l1][l]{${}+bbb$}}]
    \addplot {x};
    \addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One may simplify the usage. Whether there is a stable way to marry this to `externalize` I do not know.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept soon if there are no suggestions on what to do with `externalize`. I'm very new to `pgf` but it seems all but the most trivial cases require the `externalize` option to have anything compile due to size limitations. i.e. imported data needs to be further discretized into smaller sets which is difficult for curves with fine structure.